# No resource found that matches color/holo_blue_dark

Tags: android, android-resources

I am getting this error on my android application in eclipse.
Error Msg:
    Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value "@android:color/holo_blue_dark")

What does it mean and how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you imported appcompact library?

Comment: increase your api level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mean that resource is not available.

```
@android:color/holo_blue_dark
```

This resource is available from the api level 11 and above, to resolve that make sure your minimum sdk level in manifest is 11+ also api level for android is also 11+

Comment: How can I do that ? Sorry I am new to android and eclipse.

Comment: go to manifest find the tag minimum sdk level and change it to 11 or 11+ i.e; 12,13,14 up to 20 depending upon the API level you have downloaded from sdk manager, also right click on project go to properties-->Android and select saem API level you have set in manifest.

Comment: I have this one in the manifest file: android:minSdkVersion="9" and    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

Comment: minSdkVersion="11" change it like this

Comment: ok and what should I select in the properties-->Android ? I mean which version of android ?

Comment: same 11, upvote and accept the answer if that help you to remove that bug

Comment: that error is fixed but a new error still coming which is: no resource identifier found for attribute 'adsize' in package